# Android - create library or core app for similiar apps

Tags: android

I have several apps whose behavior is the same, but only a few different sub menus. the problem is, when there should be a change, i have to modify all the apps. I want to create a core library of these applications. My idea is, I create a library, in the library I create a class to handle the main layout. then on apps calling the class from the library.

class from the library I will create :

```
public class LayoutActivity extends LinearLayout {

private View mLayout;
private Button button;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

public LayoutActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

public LayoutActivity(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    mLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, this, true);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

}

public View getLayout() {
    return mLayout;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

class from my app :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LayoutActivity layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    layout = new LayoutActivity(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(layout.getLayout());

}
```

however when I enter TabLayout on the layout of my library, I get an error like this:

[image]

when I didn't enter a component like Tab Layout or Toolbar I did not get any error.

Does anyone know this error why? or is there another idea to create libraries from my apps?

Comment: Can you show your xml layout?

Comment: I will not make xml layout on my application
I created the xml layout on my library. I just put Button and TabLayout wrapped in LinearLayout

Comment: Seems that there is an error in the xml in your library